# How to make a cache entry in websphere not to expire

Tags: caching, websphere, distributed-caching

I have created a cache in the web sphere which will be shared by multiple applications and i wanted to make one entry in the created cache to not to expire. How can i make it ?

Thanks and Regards,

Sunny.

Comment: ...in that cache? Perhaps you could be a bit more descriptive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you deriving/using WebSpheres dyna-cache (DistributedObjectCache)? How are you creating your cache instance?

The `DistributedObjectCache` (through it's `DistributedMap` parent) defines a "put" method overload that accepts a TTL for the individual cache entry. If you want to set the TTL for the entire cache, there is conversely a `setTimeToLive(int)` method in `DistributedMap`

see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6rxmx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wsps.602.javadoc.doc/doc/com/ibm/websphere/cache/DistributedMap.html

Worth noting is that the TTL is not available as a configuration option in the cacheinstances.properties (or the admin console Resources/Cache Instances/Object cache instances), it has to be set programatically using `setTimeToLive()`

Comment: Thanks for this information. I observe default time to live around 5 minutes. I suppose there is a default TTL, is that right ? And how can we configure it with no code (as property name/value through the administrative console ?)